# If the Account has Expired, Delete the Account Details

Tags: notepad++, regex

What regular expression would I need to `delete all the expired accounts`.

```
Name: John Smith
Address: 123 Sample Road
Country: England
Membership Expires: January 26, 2023, 9:35 am -288 Days
Plan: Platinum
Payment Method: American Express


Name: Paul Mitchell
Address: 911 Unknown Road
Country: USA
Membership Expires: October 7, 2024, 10:23 am 331 Days
Plan: Gold
Payment Method: Visa


Name: David Beckham
Address: 666 Example Road
Country: Scotland
Membership Expires: August 30, 2023, 6:03 pm -72 Days
Plan: Silver
Payment Method: Mastercard


Name: Frank Bruno
Address: 999 Random Road
Country: France
Membership Expires: April 19, 2024, 10:41 pm 160 Days
Plan: Bronze
Payment Method: PayPal
```

**What I want:**

```
Name: Paul Mitchell
Address: 911 Unknown Road
Country: USA
Membership Expires: October 7, 2024, 10:23 am 331 Days
Plan: Gold
Payment Method: Visa


Name: Frank Bruno
Address: 999 Random Road
Country: France
Membership Expires: April 19, 2024, 10:41 pm 160 Days
Plan: Bronze
Payment Method: PayPal
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? [Edit] your question instead of replying with a comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^Name:(?:(?!Name:|-).)+-\d+ Days(?:(?!Name:|-).)+(?=Name:|\z)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **TICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                       # beginning of line
Name:                   # literally
(?:(?!Name:|-).)+       # 1 or more any character but not "Name:" or "-"
-\d+                    # minus followed by 1 or more digits
 Days
(?:(?!Name:|-).)+       # 1 or more any character but not "Name:" or "-"
(?=Name:|\z)            # positive lookahead, make sure we have after: "Name:" or end-of-file
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/ZjItIp/1)

Comment: Is `(^.+\R){3}^.+-\d+\sDays\R(^.+\R){2}` an alternative?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: Yes it is, but it will not work if there is an extra line somewhere in a block.